# restore mdadm raid5 after 2 of 3 disks have been reformated with xfs

Tags: raid, restore, mdadm, raid-5

I have a 3 disk raid 5 where 2 disks have been accidentally formatted with the xfs file system.

The disks are partitioned into 6 partitions - sd[a,b,c][1-6]

The disks were present in a Buffalo Terrastation NAS. I just powered down the NAS, removed the disks and booted up a Linux live CD with the disks attached.

```
mdadm --examine /dev/sda6 reports nothing
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sda6
mdadm --examine /dev/sdb6 reports nothing
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdb6
mdadm --examine /dev/sdc6 reports nothing
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdc6
```

By accident sda6, sdb6 and sdc6 have been formatted with to the xfs file system.

I mounted it as read-only for testing. It is empty - just 5 empty folders created by default by the Buffalo NAS. No real data has been written so far to the disks.

I replaced one of the disks from the raid 6 weeks again and kept it:

```
mdadm --examine /dev/sdd6 reports raid5 with 4 disks.
```

So this is the only disk, that still knows there was a raid. Is there a change to restore the superblocks and assemble the raid again?

Comment: You have no chance.

Comment: So did you format _two_ disks or _three_?

Comment: @grawity i formated all 3 disks. The 4. disk was a disk i replace a while ago and just kept.

Comment: Then you're beyond screwed. The 4th disk isn't going to be in sync with the others even if you CAN recover data from it. You *Might* be able to rebuild the partitions for the raid and access the data this way, but I personally would be restoring from backups already.

Comment: You have backups right?